# Form Submission- success

Tags: php, jquery, forms

well I have a very weird Form Submission problem on which I wasted days and still cannot figure it out: 
1) when I fill in the form properly (for a new user) works well
2) if I try to register a user with an existing email... it just refreshes instead of throwing an error
3) if I submit the form after a failed attempt I do not receive any success sign although data has been submitted to the database
here is my code:

```
 $(function() {  
 $("#send").click(function() {  
    // validate and process form here  
//var email = $("#email").val();
//var lname =  $("input#lname").val();
var dataString = $("#pForm").serialize();
//alert (dataString);
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/insertUser.php",
            data: dataString,
            success:function(msg, status){
        //alert (dataString);
        var reply = parseInt(msg);
        alert(status+ "" + msg);
        if(reply ==1){
            alert('Email address already exists in our members database.\nPlease try another address and then submit it again!');
        }
        else if(reply ==2){ //do nothing
        //  alert('You have one or more empty fields!\nPlease provide all the information required and then submit it again!');
        }
        else if(reply == 0){
        $('#pForm').hide('fast');
        $('#accForm').show('slow');
        }
                              }
                });      

  });  
});
```

and my php looks like this:

```
 <?php 
 include ('databaseCon.php');
 $err = 0;
//echo $data= $_POST['dataString'];
 $accType = $_POST['accType'];
 $fname =$_POST['fname'];
 $lname = $_POST['lname'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 $country = $_POST['country'];
 $state = $_POST['state'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];



 // check for empty fields
 if (($accType == "") || ($fname == "") || ($lname == "") || ($email == "") || ($country == "") || ($city == "")){
$empty = true;
}

if ($email != ""){
    $em = mysql_query("Select Email from Users where Email = '$email';") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_num_rows($em);

    }
//else{echo "unknown error 2 " + $email + "\n";}
    if ($empty == false){
        //echo ""+ $accType +"\n"+ $fname +"\n"+ $lname +"\n"+ $email +"\n"+ $country +"\n"+  $state +"\n"+ $city + "" ;
        if($row == 0){
        echo $users = mysql_query("Insert into Users values('','$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$accType', '$country', '$state', '$city');") or die(mysql_error());   
        }
        else{
            $err = 1;}
        }
    else{
    $err = 2;
    }
 echo $err;

 ?>
```

Any ideas and thanks for your help!

Comment: Check your HTML and see if the submit button is indeed within a <form> tag.  If it is, since the form is being processed via ajax it will refresh the page once the ajax return has finished executing.

Comment: Try to use something like Firebug firefox extension and then you can see whether your post data and response is in the valid format. It will help you to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested by implementing an error handler on the ajax call?

On an unrelated note, you really need to use some form of data escaping/database protection with your queries, preferably with prepare.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(reply ==1){
    alert('Email address already exists in our members database.\nPlease try another address and then submit it again!');
    return false;
}
```

Try this.